# Checking the presence of a div

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have a div named container as shown

```
<div id='container'>50</div>
```

Now if I use

```
var a = document.getElementById('container').value;
var b = document.getElementById('container1').value;
```

Here a, is fine but b gives an error

SO, is there any way to check whether a div is present or not, if, its there, I will obtain its value

Comment: Nice one . I will follow it :)

Comment: a will not error but will return `undefined` as the `div` element has no value property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.getElementById` will return `undefined` if no element is found on the page. So, you can explicitly check for `undefined` before trying to access the value.

```
var element = document.getElementById('container1');
if (element != undefined) //note: this can be shortened to just "if (element)"
{
    alert(element.value);
}
```

Comment: I have seen 'undefined' to be not all that reliable on older browsers. In any case it will give something that evaluates to a boolean false.

Comment: @Eugen can you elaborate? The only way that would go wrong is if someone clobbers `undefined`, which would be rare.

Comment: `if( element )` is bulletproof, easier to read and shorter to write. What's not to like? It also returns `null` not undefined if element is not found but that doesn't matter.

Comment: @wsanville "if (element==undefined) alert('undefined');" Will not work on Windows Mobile. "if (!element) alert('undefined');" will.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a=null;
var b=null;
var o = document.getElementById('container');
if (o) a=o.value;
o = document.getElementById('container1');
if (o) b=o.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

`var b = (document.getElementById('container1') || 0).value;`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/rogerblanton/Va99D/

```
var a = document.getElementById('container').value;
var b = document.getElementById('container1');
if ( b > 0  ) {
    b.value;
}
```